# Rails DB error when trying to include associated model to JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, sqlite

I'm trying to build a messaging system through an API using Rails 4.

**Models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "sender_id"
 has_many :received_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", primary_key: "sender_id"
 belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", primary_key: "recipient_id"
end
```

**Migrations:**

```
class DeviseTokenAuthCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table(:users) do |t|

   ...

   ## User Info
   t.string :name

   ...

  end
 end
end
```

and

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :messages do |t|

    t.string :msg_body

    t.belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", primary_key: "sender_id", index: true
    t.belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", primary_key: "recipient_id", index: true
    t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

Message **Controller:**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

 def index
  messages = Message.all
  render :json => messages.as_json(:include => [:sender, :recipient])
 end

end
```

**PROBLEM**

The thing is, when I go for a GET request of all the messages, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.sender_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."sender_id" = ? LIMIT 1)
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Why? What can I do about this?

Comment: `primary_key: "sender_id"`, it's `foreign_key`, same with the `recipient_id` one

Comment: whelp, it is indeed. thank you so much! I was so convinced I made the models the right way that I only looked in the migrations for errors or missing information.

If you want to add this as an answer I'll get it as the right answer! thanks again

Comment: it's okay, no worries. we almost never specify `primary_key` in the association since it's almost always gonna be just `id`